# How to rectify "Removed records" error in openpyxl (Python)?

Tags: python-3.6, openpyxl

Using openpyxl after removing the unwanted worksheet, If I open the .xlsx file it shows an error "We found a problem with some content in 'file.xlsx'. Click Yes if you trust this file". After clicking Yes I'm getting a window 
"Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)". This occurs only if I remove some worksheets. Please help me to rectify this problem. My code to remove worksheet is as follows

```
for s in sheet_name:
    if s != 'Sheet1':
        wb.remove(wb[s])
```

Comment: You're probably removing worksheets to which the defined names contain references.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can I remove the other sheets after copying the required data from them without getting this error